# Allow admin user to give permission to customer registration in Magento shop

Tags: customer, administration

I want to set a rule to allow administrator to give permission to customers when they register an account in the Magento Shop. Currently, Customers can register an account without asking Administrator's permission.

Anyone here knows about how to do it or any extensions I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I know the Vinai has an extension for [Customer Activation](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation) which means that a customer after registration must be activated by an admin before they can actually login to the website.